# Why does GridBagLayout anchor not work for multiple buttons?

Tags: java, swing, anchor, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to stack two buttons on top of each other and anchor them to the top of a panel, but the second button stays in the center of the panel.

In this code, I create a split pane and then add two panels to it.  One panel contains the buttons (the panel that I am interested in) and the other contains a text field.  The buttons make some text appear in the text field.

I would like to figure out which right combination of GridBagLayout parameters will allow me to put two buttons on top of each other (with no gaps in between) and anchor them to the top of the panel.  I have tried a few different things with the weighting and gridy parameter, but to no avail.

Thank you in advance for your time and responses.

```
package gridbagtest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame gridTest = new JFrame("Grid Bag Layout Test");

        JSplitPane splitPaneHorizontal = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);

        final JTextField blah = new JTextField(30);
        JPanel textPane = new JPanel();
        textPane.add(blah);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.gridx = 0;
//      c.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;

        JButton flightPlanButton = new JButton("First Button");

        flightPlanButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {   blah.setText("First Button pushed");    }
         });

        buttonPane.add(flightPlanButton, c);

        JButton powerButton = new JButton("Second Button");
        powerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()                            
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {   blah.setText("Second Button pushed");   }
        });

        c.gridy = 1;
        buttonPane.add(powerButton, c);

        splitPaneHorizontal.setTopComponent(new JScrollPane(buttonPane));
        splitPaneHorizontal.setBottomComponent(textPane);   

        gridTest.add(splitPaneHorizontal);
        gridTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gridTest.pack();
        gridTest.setSize(600,800);
        gridTest.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840044/java-gridbaglayout-anchor

Answer (score 2):

I think that one problem is that you're not adding anything beneath the buttons to fill up the empty space. There are many ways to solve this. One is avoid GridBagLayout entirely, put the JButtons in a JPanel that uses BoxLayout, and put that JPanel into another that uses BorderLayout at the BorderLayout.PAGE_START (or NORTH) position. Another, which I'll show has you set the weighty of your buttons to 0, and then add another component such as an empty JLabel or here I use glue from the box class, give it a decent weighty, a decent height, say remainder, and see what happens:

```
  JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
  buttonPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  buttonPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;
  c.weightx = 1;
  c.weighty = 0;

  JButton flightPlanButton = new JButton("First Button");

  flightPlanButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        blah.setText("First Button pushed");
     }
  });

  buttonPane.add(flightPlanButton, c);

  JButton powerButton = new JButton("Second Button");

  c.gridy = 1;
  buttonPane.add(powerButton, c);

  c.gridy = 2;
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
  c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
  c.weighty = 100.0;
  c.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
  buttonPane.add(Box.createGlue(), c);
```

Also, I believe that what Devon_C_Miller states, that you need to create a new GridBagConstraint if you are changing fields, is not true, and in fact Oracle defies this in its own GridBagLayout API.

One more bit to Devon_C_Miller: to be sure, I checked the GridBagLayout source code, and found that the class stores this information in a `HashTable<Component, GridBagConstraints>` variable called *comptable*, and that in the `setConstraints(...)` method where information is placed in this table, the GridBagConstraints object is *cloned* first before it is added to the table, proving completely that there is no need to create a new GridBagConstraints object (although often it is good programming practice to do so but for other reasons).

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller: please see edit to answer for more on GridBagConstraints.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This offered an easy solution.  I was using GridBagLayout because BoxLayout was giving me fits with its horizontal filling. Adding the empty box at the end solves my problems.
As an aside I had two more questions, just for future reference.  
1. Does the weight needs to be anything greater than 1 (I had thought the scale is from 0 to 1.0)?
2. Are both the fill 'BOTH' and the gridheight 'REMAINDER' needed (I tried either and it seemed to have the same effect)?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code if you add a new GridBagConstraints object and use it for the second button add.

```
        GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
        d.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        d.gridx = 0;
        d.gridy = 0;
        d.weightx = 0;
        d.weighty = 0;
```

Then use it in your add.

```
        buttonPane.add(flightPlanButton, d);
```

I ran this code and it stacked the buttons like you want them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I wasn't able to get this to work