# How to remove these space from the Pane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout, jmenubar

Here is the key code:

```
  public GridBagConstraints setGridBagC(int gx,int gy,double wx,double wy,int gFill,int gAnchor){
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill=gFill;
        c.anchor=gAnchor;
        c.gridx=gx;
        c.gridy=gy; 
        c.weightx=wx;
        c.weighty=wy;
        return c;
}
```

---

```
public int initFrame(Container pane){
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT);//Set the size of the frame.
        setResizable(false);//You're not allowed to resize the frame.   
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());    
        GridBagConstraints c;       c=setGridBagC(0,0,0,0,GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        JMenu ArchJ=new JMenu("Console");
        JMenu menuTwo=new JMenu("MenuTwo");
        JMenu menuThree=new JMenu("MenuThree");
        JMenu menuFour=new JMenu("MenuFour");
        JMenuBar mbar=new JMenuBar();
        mbar.add(ArchJ);
        JMenuItem OneItOne=new JMenuItem("1");
        OneItOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
        JMenuItem OneItTwo=new JMenuItem("2");
        OneItTwo.setSize(100, 30);
        ArchJ.add(OneItOne);
        ArchJ.addSeparator();
        ArchJ.add(OneItTwo);
        mbar.add(menuTwo);
        mbar.add(menuThree);
        mbar.add(menuFour);
        pane.add(mbar,c);
        JButton bt=new JButton("kd");
        c=setGridBagC(0,1,1.0,0,GridBagConstraints.BOTH,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        pane.add(bt,c);     
        //pack();//Do not use pack()
        return 1;
    }
```

And this is the initiation of `frame`:

```
RobotCtrlFrame frame=new RobotCtrlFrame();
frame.initFrame(frame.getContentPane());
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I don't intend to use the function `pack()` here. The space left at the top and buttom confuses me a lot. How can I eliminate these space? Thanks.
Though using `pack();` can wrap up the space.I'd like to figure out the reason of these left space.

Comment: try to use an anchor. Example c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;. It should place the components at the top given you use the appropriate c.weighty and c.weightx. More documentation on using anchor [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Also please do not create a separate method to deal with the constraints because of the sheer amount of parameters you need to pass and I only see it as an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The 'menuBar' is on the top of the pane now by setting:'weighty=(not zero);' and 'c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START'. Thanks for your suggestions also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks for your code. I just want to try another way to set the
>   MenuBar by using the Layout

- [JMenuBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) isn't designated to be placed to the [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html), but is possible to set anchor  in [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)
- add [JMenuBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) to [JFrame(or JDialog ...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) by using [JFrame.setMenuBar(MenuBar mb)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setMenuBar%28java.awt.MenuBar%29) not (as our code demonstrated) to the [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and by using quite complex [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1):

Im not great on swing myself. But have you tried changing weightx and/or weighty to 1 instead of 0. As stated in this question: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840044/java-gridbaglayout-anchor) Just something to try.

Comment: I think its weighty thats the important one

Comment: You got the reason?Please share with us.

Comment: As I understand it, when the weightings are both equal to 0, java uses its default condition which is to centralize the components in the center of the screen, which is what happened with yours. Therefore, if you have at least one not-zero weighting then this over rides the default. For any more information, I always found this link to be helpful: [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). If my answer worked, could you please accept it or upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to add label with space(not empty)  to the last line (for you gridy = 2) and **weighty** property set to 1. This trick must work

Answer (score 1):

Type cast `pane` to `JFrame` and set the menu bar using `setJMenuBar` in `JFrame` class.
Here is the sample program

```
package com.sample.ui;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class TestJFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3509944903365488258L;

    public TestJFrame() {
        super();
        initFrame(this);
    }

    public GridBagConstraints setGridBagC(int gx, int gy, double wx, double wy,
            int gFill, int gAnchor) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = gFill;
        c.anchor = gAnchor;
        c.gridx = gx;
        c.gridy = gy;
        c.weightx = wx;
        c.weighty = wy;
        return c;
    }

    public int initFrame(Container pane) {
        setSize(300, 300);// Set the size of the frame.
        setResizable(false);// You're not allowed to resize the frame.
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c;
        c = setGridBagC(0, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        JMenu ArchJ = new JMenu("Console");
        JMenu menuTwo = new JMenu("MenuTwo");
        JMenu menuThree = new JMenu("MenuThree");
        JMenu menuFour = new JMenu("MenuFour");
        JMenuBar mbar = new JMenuBar();
        mbar.add(ArchJ);
        JMenuItem OneItOne = new JMenuItem("1");
        OneItOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        JMenuItem OneItTwo = new JMenuItem("2");
        OneItTwo.setSize(100, 30);
        ArchJ.add(OneItOne);
        ArchJ.addSeparator();
        ArchJ.add(OneItTwo);
        mbar.add(menuTwo);
        mbar.add(menuThree);
        mbar.add(menuFour);

        JFrame jFrame = (JFrame) pane;
        jFrame.setJMenuBar(mbar);

        JButton bt = new JButton("kd");
        c = setGridBagC(0, 1, 1.0, 0, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        pane.add(bt, c);
        // pack();//Do not use pack()
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJFrame testJFrame = new TestJFrame();
        testJFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I just want to try another way to set the `MenuBar` by using the `Layout`.